# Is it possible to fade out a table row on passing to the next?

Tags: beamer, overlays

I have table, a sample attached as a MWE. I am able to show one row at a time. I was wondering if it is possible to fade out the row above, after am through presenting it.
I am not able to find any post which suggests this is possible, but if it is, I will appreciate help.
N.B. my document also contains graphics (not in the table. This is why there are other packages loaded, which have nothing to do with this MWE.
Thanks

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\mode<presentation> {
\usepackage[font=Times,timeinterval=10, timeduration=2.0, timedeath=0, fillcolorwarningsecond=white!60!yellow, timewarningfirst=50,timewarningsecond=80,resetatpages=2]{tdclock}
}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\setbeamertemplate{enumerate mini template}{\insertenumlabel}
\setbeamercovered{invisible}
\setbeamercovered{%
  again covered={\opaqueness<1->{15}}}

\usepackage{graphicx} % Allows including images
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[caption=false]{subfig}
\usepackage{booktabs} % Allows the use of \toprule, \midrule and \bottomrule in tables
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{pbox}
\usepackage[]{mathabx}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{shapepar}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}

\newcommand\circlenodetext[3]{\node [draw, shape=circle, text width=0cm, inner sep=2mm] at (#1,#2) {\shapepar{\circleshape} #3\par};}
\newcommand\squarenodetext[3]{\node [draw, regular polygon, regular polygon sides=4, text width=0cm, inner sep=0mm] at (#1,#2) {\shapepar{\squareshape} #3\par};}
\newcommand\diamondnodetext[3]{\node [draw, shape=diamond, text width=0cm, inner sep=2mm] at (#1,#2) {\shapepar{\diamondshape} #3\par};}

\newcommand\rectanglenodetext[3]{\node [draw,  regular polygon, regular polygon sides=4, text width=0cm, inner sep=2mm] at (#1,#2) {\shapepar{\rectangleshape} #3\par};}
\newcounter{sauvegardeenumi}
\newcommand{\asuivre}{\setcounter{sauvegardeenumi}{\theenumi}}
\newcommand{\suite}{\setcounter{enumi}{\thesauvegardeenumi}}
\setbeamertemplate{caption}{\raggedright\insertcaption\par}

\title[short title]{full title}
\author{myself}
\institute[]{where am from.\\
\medskip
\textit{my meail}
}

\date{\today}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\titlepage % to print the title page as the first slide
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\begin{tabular}[H]{|p{2.2cm} |p{2.6cm} |p{3.0cm} |p{2.2cm}|}
\toprule
\textbf{header1} & \textbf{header2} & \textbf{header3} & \textbf{header4}\\ \hline
\pbox{10cm}{first of first\\ second of first} & \pbox{10cm}{first of second\\ second of second} & \pbox{10cm}{first of third\\ second of third} & \color{black}\pbox{10cm}{first of fourth\\ second of fourth}\\ \hline\onslide<2->
\pause
\pbox{10cm}{first of second\\ second of second} & \pbox{10cm}{third of second\\ second of second} & \pbox{10cm}{first of third\\ second of third} & \color{black}\pbox{10cm}{first of fourth\\ second of fourth}\\ \hline
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: What's the purpose of a `\pbox{10cm}` inside of a `p{2.2cm}` column?

Comment: My understanding is that this is to enable me to put a column entry on two lines or more.

Comment: So simply achieve linebreaks in `p`type columns, the `\pbox` is not needed. With that, you actually try to place a 10 cm wide box inside of a table column that is only 2.2cm wide. If you want manual linebreaks inside of a `p` type column, you can simply use `first of first\newline second of first & first of second\newline second of second &` or entirely remove the manual linebreaks and let latex add linebreaks where needed

Comment: Thanks very much @ leandriis. That is very useful for me to learn that., I am still anxious on my main question, whether it is possible to fade out the previous row of a table.

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "fade out"? Do you want to get the first row of the table on the first slide and the second row on the second slide with a) the first row not showing p at all or b) with the first row showing up in a gray, less visible, text color or c) someting entirely different?

Comment: What am try to do is to have the first row showing in gray once the second row comes

Comment: @leandriis, just to say you weren't pinged in the last comment